# Selenium TestNG - DataProvider with 1D Array for Yahoo Search

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, testng

I tried a search scenario using Yahoo search. But only the first element in the array is been searched. The same code is working properly for Google search. Code as Follows:

```
package googleSearch;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class YahooSearch {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D://chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com"); 
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void quit(){
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.quit();
    }

    @DataProvider (name="Searchtext")
    public Object [][] data(){
    return new Object [][] {{"Teacher"},{"School"}};
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="Searchtext")
    public void search(String text) {
    WebElement txtsearch = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='p_13838465-p']"));
    txtsearch.sendKeys(text);
    WebElement btnSub= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='search-submit']"));
    btnSub.submit();
    }    
}
```

The Error displays as follows:

```
PASSED: search("Teacher")
FAILED: search("School")

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=37.0.2062.120)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 64 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.29.0', revision: '58258c3', time: '2013-01-17 22:47:00'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: 9df485bf13d7a846a1be5a3d9e0e9570
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\Aloka\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4652_2250}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=37.0.2062.120, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:533)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:302)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:387)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:294)
    at googleSearch.YahooSearch.search(YahooSearch.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

===============================================
    Default test

## Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not finding element.

Locate element better with chrome -> open your page -> check element -> rightclick on element -> Copy CSS path(or xpath if U want). 
Use this css in locator.

Comment: The above code is accepting the first item of the array. So I think the Web Element is ok.

Comment: Try run with only one element.

Comment: @Test(dataProvider="Searchtext")
    public void search(String text) {
    WebElement txtsearch = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='p_13838465-p']"));
    txtsearch.sendKeys(text);
    txtsearch.click();
    //WebElement btnSub= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='search-submit']"));
    //btnSub.submit();
    }